# Is it possible to get a new Minecraft *game* id without getting a new *user id* / buying a new copy of Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

There is some sort of a global "player id" that identifies you to Minecraft servers. This id has a 1:1 relationship with a game state on a server. Is it possible to get a new game on a server without getting a new id (without buying a new copy of Minecraft)? This would make it possible to start from fresh on a server one doesn't control.

I think that the whole idea of there being a *single game state* associated with a *single user id* is, on its face, absurd. When you play locally, you can have as many games as you wish. The same should be possible on a server. I have no problem with having a unique id so that someone can ban me etc. I just wish there was a way to have more than one game state (player state) on a server, so that I could explore different strategies etc.

My question is not about impersonating another player, nor avoiding bans, etc. I simply wonder why online play limits the functionality present in the basic local Minecraft - namely that you can have more than one game state.

Comment: would be intresting if my answer meets your claims...

Answer (score 5):

That would be very bad, if it would be working. It is of course not working. The game is linked with you account and it is not possible to change that.

The ID was earlier your in game name. With your name you will be identified from the servers. The name is not changeable in an easy way. The only way is to contact the support (but they wont change it).

Now it is working with a unique ID (v1.7.6). Means you are able to change your name but not your ID.

> This version provides complete support for identifying players through
> unique IDs and not by names, so that no matter what a player is called
> they will remain banned/whitelisted/oped/etc on servers.

<sub>from [mojang](https://mojang.com/2014/04/minecraft-1-7-6-pre-release/)</sub>

The reason why you cannot change your ID is because server owner have a problem to identify you. Means if you are banned from a server, you should be banned and not have a chance to join.

---

**Answer for your edited question:**

The functionality on a server is basically the same as on a local game. You actually can not have more "games", but you can have more worlds! On a Server it is exactly the same (if the owner has build it like so). If the server owner has nothing edited and just has a bunch of different maps, you have a "new game/status" on every map. There is nothing limited.

Anyway the chance that there is a server that is build up like that is very low, because everyone wants to keep his items and build just one house and that on just one map. If there are more than one map it is likely a mini game map, pvp, skyland or whatever.

There is no possibility (legal and playable on all "online" servers) in any way to get a new status/"game" on a server by changing anything at your client or on your account.

The only way is to ask the server owner to delete your user data from the server.

Comment: actually the ID changed to a GUID rather than your player name to assist in name changes

Comment: @ratchetfreak yea you are right thx, I searched for it an found it also on the original site. I put that in my answer!

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer your question: No it's currently not possible because Mojang did not program it that way.

Your question is essentially: Why did the developers of a game not implement this feature?
Who knows?

I agree with you it would be a great feature to on each server be able to create progress saves as a different entity in each save but still be identifiable as the same person but it is simply not a feature at the moment.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, there are multiple name changing mods out there but a bunch of them are either within hacking clients or really glitchy. Also, in order for the name change to actually work, the server must be in offline mode. There is no easy way to find out if it is actually offline.

The hacking client i use is called [nodus](http://www.wizardhax.com/nodus/) in case you were wondering. Inside the nodus hacking client, in order to change your name, just enter either the multiplayer menu or the options menu, there should be an add account button. Press that and fill out the desired boxes.

**Note:** They are just called hacking clients, they don't do any literal hacking, they just allow you to break blocks faster, add a forcefield, walk on water, fly, use the x-ray mod, and much more BUT most servers also have anti hacking client addons or mods that will just ban automagically you from the server if you are caught using them.

Another note, if you wish to start fresh on a server then **politely** ask the owner of the server to delete your account by going into the the worlds folder and entering the players folder and finding your minecraft id. The path of this would be `[server_folder]/[world_name]/players`. What ever is in the `[]` is the whatever the folder might be named.

Comment: @Gerret I don't want to impersonate anyone, just disassociate myself from the state on the server to start fresh. I find it very strange that a such a simple thing isn't available.

Comment: @KubaOber The "id" wich you are autenticated with the server is mostly the name. There is also the possibility to use youre ip address. But youre name is not changeable. The only way is to buy a new one or contact the support. The way of Baked Potato will work mostly but only on **offline** servers that do not check youre name. With offline i mean the online mode of the server

Comment: @KubaOber Well this isn't entirely impersonating, you can make up a new name. Also, judging by your previous question, if you want to start fresh on a server, either start a new server or **politely** ask the server OWNER(not the mod or anything) to delete your name file from the world's folder. Also, if this "simple" thing was incorporated there might be a lot of chaos from people actually impersonating others and it is also very difficult to code.

Comment: @KubaOber that "simple thing" would be a huge problem for server maintainers, they wouldnt  have a unique user to deal with then.

Comment: @BakedPotato you are able to impersonation with that tool but only on server where the server online mode is on offline because they do not check the name. That is the reason why servers for cracked minecraft games you have to enter a password because you can take the name you want.

Comment: I really, ***really*** don't think that client is something we should be recommending to players here on Arqade. While it *might* do what the question is asking for, I feel it's like solving someone's FPS problems with "Just download this aimbot". Which is all kinds of no.

Comment: @Gerret I know, I used to go on that kind of a server AND also used to own one. My argument is that it isn't entirely impersonating. YES you can impersonate someone with that tool but you can also make a "new" account. Example: does anyone anywhere have the id of "fikwoefnderfegr"? **Note that this is just an example.**

Comment: @TrentHawkins I see what you are trying to say there but it is just the only mod I know that can do that. Also, the way I was trying to write this answer was "Here I can solve your name problem with this mod that has a name changing option BUT it also just so happens to have aimbot" Also, there is nothing wrong with that mod in my opinion, I have seen plenty of server that actually ask you to use such mods to make the server time more fun. Example: Imagine a battle of gods where in this sense the gods are the players and the powers are mods like this. It is his choice whether he want it or not

Comment: @BakedPotato I do not know now what you want to say me... I am just telling you the legal way and the way so you are able to play on the original minecraft server with a online mode on true.

Comment: @Gerret I guess I got confused somewhere in these barrages of comments.... Sorry if i confused you myself, I'm just trying to protect my answer

Comment: @BakedPotato Ye no problem, I cleared and edited my answer now. I think now it is easy to understand. Keep in mind I am just telling you the legal way and the way you are able to play on all onlinemode:true servers!!

Comment: @RandomDisplayName The unique user ID could be there, there'd be simply more than one game state per user ID. Remember that on any given server, there already is either 0 or 1 game states per user. It'd be a simple matter to extend it to more than 1. Just like you can in local play. It'd come with no downsides and would be a simple way to protect from simple mistakes and allow exploration and trying things out. I'm still baffled that this is not available.